# Creating a delay during loadtest in soapUI

Tags: soapui, load-testing

I want to make a load test in soapUI that will run for example 10 threads during 2 hours but with a delay in 30 min after each two threads. Is it possible?

Comment: So. t0 + t1 for first 30 min then t2+t3 for the following 30 minutes? or are you saying: let two threads run, then when they are done let 30 minutes pass then begin 2 threads, etc? or something else?

Comment: I meant the second option, when two threads are done and then a pause for 30 min

Answer (score 0):

The best option you have would be to use a Simple strategy.

- Strategy: Simple
- Threads: 2
- Test Delay: 1800000
- Random: 0
- Limit: 10 Total Runs

The downfall here is that it will not run the first iteration until 30 minutes pass. The other way you could possibly pull this off with more customization would be a Script strategy.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, but this won't help me... As far as I understand, Test Delay is a timeout between two threads ("Sets delay between each test run"), so I set it to 0, as I need parallel threads. And I do need to set 10 threads, not 2, because for each thread I have different data (I have groovy script before soap request that adds contex.ThreadIndex to some values so that they are not the same for each thread)